# Option Value Changed - ODBC Error 2169

Tags: advantage-database-server

I am connecting to ADS through ODBC DSN. Everything works well until I tried 
out my Save Routine. Data is saved quite alright but I get an error that 
says - "Option value changed". What could this be? Can't find in the help 
file.

The full error message is:

ODBC - 2169
[iAnywhere Solutions][Advantage ODBC Driver] Option Value Changed.

I sent an email in respect of this to advantage@extendsys.com since this 
error
number falls between error numbers: 2168 - 2188 Internal Error that should 
be reported.

I posted this question on the Newsgroup without a possitive response.

Best regards,

Fredrick Ughimi
support@ughimisoft.com

Answer (score 3):

For ODBC, in general, "Option Value Changed" typically indicates that a request was made that was not valid or not supported by the driver so the driver substituted similar value.  Typically this type of error is informational or in other words sql_success_with_info.  I suggest looking into an ODBC trace as it may help uncover what was changed or at least narrow down what was occurring.
It may also be helpful to post information about your save routine.